# WPF Formatting string as currency using the € symbol

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, string-formatting

I've got an application where I need to show a price, for that, I have the following code:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Prijs}" ContentStringFormat="C"></Label>
```

However, that gives a stringformat like: $10.00, but i want to show the euro-sign (€) instead of the dollar-sign ($). How do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make sure that the `Language` of the control is set correctly.

Tim Heuer has a [blog post](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/08/11/stringformat-and-currentculture-in-silverlight.aspx) entitled "StringFormat and CurrentCulture in Silverlight" about this for Silverlight so I expect the same problem occurs in WPF.

The solution for Silverlight is to add the following line to the view constructor:

```
this.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);
```

Now for WPF you might just need to make sure that the `CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` is set correctly, if not try adding this line too.

Comment: For many UserControls you can just set the ConverterCulture Attribute and it'll work, at least in WPF. Don't know about Silverlight.